# for loop populates array with numbers

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop

I am trying to populate an array with numbers from 1 to the length of my array. But, it isn't working. What could I do different to fix it?

```
var numArray = new Array(48);

for(i=0;i>=numArray.length;i++) {
    numArray[i] = numArray.push(i+1);
}
```

Comment: Change the line as;
`numArray[i] = i+1;`

Comment: You could do:  `numArray[i] = i +1`.

Comment: my output is ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"  :c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, your loop will not actually run because the condition `i >= numArray.length` will immediately be false, since `i == 0` and `numArray.length == 48`. To fix this, change the loop to

```
// this will loop as long as i is less than the length of the array
// i.e. i = 0, i = 1, i = 2, ...
for (var i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) {
```

Also, you are not adding numbers to the array in the way that you think. `numArray.push(i+1)` adds the number to the end of the array, which will be starting at index 48. You can simply use

```
numArray[i] = i + 1;
```

to add the number to the array. If you have to use the `push` method, and you know that your array has to have a length of 48, you can do

```
var numArray = new Array(0);
for (var i = 0; i < 48; i++) {
    numArray.push(i + 1);
}
```

Comment: How helpful, thank you. A silly mistake on my part, certainly.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it like this;

```js
var numArray = (new Array(48)).fill("whatever").map((e,i) => i+1);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(numArray, 0, 2) + '</pre>');
```